# Getting Mysql Connection Error with docker compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup my development env using docker & docker compose.I am using Django with Mysql & phpymyadmin.Whener I run `docker-compose up` command my mysql & phpmyadmin images setups properly but my Django app fails & throws this error,

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL
> server on '192.168.1.221' (115)")

Here is my yaml file.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver"
    container_name: demo
    volumes:
      - .:/data
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  base:
```

Here is my Dockerfile for django app.

```
# Dockerfile


FROM python:3.8

# install nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-recommends
RUN pip install mysql-connector
COPY nginx.default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
# RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
#     && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

# The enviroment variable ensures that the python output is set straight
# to the terminal with out buffering it first
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# create root directory for our project in the container
RUN mkdir /opt/app

# set working dir
WORKDIR /opt/app

# ENV PORT=8000

EXPOSE 8000

# Copy the project files to working dir
COPY . /opt/app

# install dependencies,  you can change it to production.txt to deploy on the production env
RUN pip install -r requirements/development.txt

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here is my env variables whic used for database connection.

```
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': env.str('DB_DATABASE'),
        'HOST': env.str('DB_HOST'),
        'USER': env.str('DB_USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD': env.str('DB_PASSWORD')
    }
}
DATABASES["default"]["ATOMIC_REQUESTS"] = True
```

I have tried & check other similiar posts on stackoverflow but they did not help.I am fairly new to Docker.Any help would appreciated.

Comment: I think you should change `DB_PORT` to `3308` as you mapped it in `docker-compose`

Comment: I did that but same error is coming.

Comment: Could you add your Django database connection info?

Comment: @Saeed added that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know more

Comment: If you look at all of the `docker-compose logs`, are there database startup messages after the application exits?  If you wait 30-60 seconds and run `docker-compose up -d` again, does it work better the second time?

Comment: @DavidMaze Now I am getting this weird error Access denied for user 'docker'@'172.18.0.1. There is no user named docker. I don't know where it is picking up that from.

Comment: I have solved the this issue bu using 5.7 version of mysql.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using a database URL to connect service (backend) to my database like that:

> db_url= "jdbc:mysql://db_user:db_password@db_host:db_port/db_name"

and it's working fine for me , don't forget to mage the same network for all services (all service belongs to the same network).